# Javascript Hashing Two Numbers

Tags: javascript, hash, lookup

I have two numbers in javascript.

They are integral coordinates.

I also have an object: `var regions = {};`

I'd like to be able to access specific objects as quickly as possible.

E.g. there could be an object at (5,-2)

What's a fast way of creating unique hashes, that do not clash, for two numbers like this?

Comment: How is `regions` created? All at once in a literal, or incrementally?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it's a networked app, so the regions are sent across websockets. They'll be multiple groups in the array. E.g. one group of regions might be around (0,0) and another around (500,20) etc

Comment: So do you get one big message you parse, or dribs and drabs?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder dribs and drabs. One object at a time is sent with contained coordinates and then stored.

Comment: Note: In general computer science terminology, '[hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)' are not unique, just reproducible (i.e. the same value always produces the same hash, but two different values could generate the same hash).Using this definition, `x^y` is a perfectly valid hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the "specific objects" you want to access are referenced by properties on `regions`. Object properties in JavaScript are named either by string names or by `Symbol` names. You'd be using strings in this case.

Since it's going to be by string, the simple solution is just create a string, and look it up with that:

```
var obj = regions[num1 + "," + num2];
```

That leaves it up to the JavaScript engine to do a good job looking up the property. JavaScript engines are **very good** (read: fast) at this, because they have to do it **a lot**.

How the engine does the lookup will depend in some measure on how the `regions` object is created. Wherever possible, modern engines will create objects that are effectively micro-classes and provide very quick resolution of property names. If you do certain things (like using `delete` on one of the properties), a modern engine may fall back to "dictionary" mode where it uses a hash lookup. This is still fast, just not as fast as the optimized form.

I doubt you'll find a quicker way that that. In theory, if `region` were a contiguous array where elements referenced contiguous arrays, the JavaScript engine could make those true arrays under the covers, and one of your example numbers is negative which would prevent a true array from being used. And you'd still be doing two lookups (the first number, then the second), and there's no guarantee it would be faster. It would certainly be more complicated.

As you've said you'll receive the information in dribs and drabs, I'd go with a simple compound string key until/unless you have a performance problem with that solution, then look at trying to get contiguous arrays happening on your target engines (converting those negative indexes into something else, which could be problematic). I doubt you'll find that the lookup is every the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array notation:

```
var regions = {}
regions[[5,-2]] = myObject;
regions[[5,-2]]; // myObject
```

Object keys can't be arrays, so under the hood `[5,-2]` will be stringified to `"5,-2"`. But I think that using array notation is more pretty than stringifying manually.

Comment: Creating an array just to create a string seems fairly roundabout, esp. if the OP's concerned primarily with performance (though I suspect performance of this op isn't going to be the chief concern).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I read that instead of concatenating strings it's better to create an array and join it at the end. But yes, the performance difference is probably negligible. I prefer this way because it's prettier.

Comment: That was a long time ago and in the context of multiple concatenations (building up something from a template, for instance). On modern JavaScript engines and esp. with a single concatenation, I'm sure the overhead isn't worth it. But of course check on one's target engines.

Comment: FWIW: https://jsfiddle.net/0276ajq3/ On current FF and Chrome, array takes twice as long; on IE11, about half-again as long. ***Total*** micro-opt, though, in real world terms either is fine. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it seems arrays are only faster when concatenating lots of strings: https://jsfiddle.net/0276ajq3/1/

Comment: Well, in that case you're doing a single array literal (which does apply to the above). In the common case of doing a template, you end up using `push` (or `a[a.length] =`), which makes it no longer work as quickly. (Totally was faster with older browsers though, I remember several years ago testing it with IE6 and things went array's way pretty easily.)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
var regions = {
    '5,-2': { ... },
    '1,3': { ... }
};
```

and then if you have the 2 numbers you could easily generate the key and access the corresponding object:

```
var x = 5;
var y = -2;
var obj = regions[x + ',' + y];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used two function `encode` and `decode`.

```
var x = 10;
var y = -3.2;

function encode(x, y) {
  return x + ',' + y;
}

function decode(code) {
  var xy = code.split(',');
  return [+xy[0], +xy[1]];
}

var code = encode(x, y);
console.log(code);
var xy = decode(code);
console.log(xy);
```

The `code` can be used as dict key value.